# Nx Module Federation with Angular - No provider for HttpClient

Tags: angular, nx-workspace, nx-angular

I have setuped a micro front-end `Nx (13.10.3)` workspace with `Angular (13.3.0)` and `@nrwl/angular (13.10.3)` module federation. When I try to load a route which is loading a remote module I am getting the error below. I have added `HttpClientModule` in the `app.module.ts`.

```
core.mjs:6500 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(RemoteEntryModule)[HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(RemoteEntryModule)[HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:11160:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11327:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11327:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11327:33)
    at NgModuleRef.get (core.mjs:21886:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:11327:33)
    at NgModuleRef.get (core.mjs:21886:33)
    at Object.get (core.mjs:21563:35)
    at lookupTokenUsingModuleInjector (core.mjs:3365:39)
    at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3477:12)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1211:1)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1165:1)
    at zone.js:1278:1
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:406:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25605:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:405:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:178:1)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:585:1)
```

Comment: Only provide it in the shell app, after the browserModule

Answer (score 4):

My team has recently gone through this process and this is what has worked for us across multiple remotes:

**Quick caveat for posterity**: avoid exposing the remote's `AppModule`, use `RemoteEntryModule` or another feature module instead e.g. `DashboardModule`, `NavigationModule`, etc. (You are already doing this in the above example using `RemoteEntryModule`)

1. Import `HttpClientModule` in your shell's `AppModule`
2. Import `HttpClientModule` in your remote's `RemoteEntryModule` or feature module.

The shell should import `BrowserModule`/`BrowserAnimationsModule` in its `AppModule`.

Individual remotes' `RemoteEntryModule`/feature modules should only import `CommonModule`.

You can import `BrowserModule`/`BrowserAnimationsModule` (in addition to your `RemoteEntryModule`/feature module) in the individual MFEs' `AppModule` so they will build and serve independently - `AppModule` code should not be exposed to the shell.